# Can Passbook Pass be accessed by Apps developed by other developer?

Tags: ios6, passbook

Can I create a passbook pass that is accessible by apps by other developers?  From what I read, it appears there is some form of authentication that entitles a companion app to access passbook passes on the phone based on passTypeId. If I share the passTypeId with other apps, then would these apps be able to read the information off my pass?

Comment: BigTuna, have you figured out how to do what you said you wanted to do in your post above?

Answer (score 2):

If you receive pkpass data from another developer's server you can display their pass and even save it to passbook. However, unless you have their pass type identifier tied to your own developer account/provisioning profile, you will NOT be able to actually view/manipulate their passes through your app. i.e. when you call [passLibrary passes] only the passes to which your app is entitled to will be returned.

Comment: So How would you write code (preferably in Swift) to do what you just said you could do - "... display their pass ..."?

Comment: hey, I have not worked on this for more than 10 years and no longer do iOS development. The information I presented was true at the time of writing but may not be true any longer as I have no idea how Apple has updated/changed their offerings.

Answer (score 1):

No. You would have to share the actual passbook certificate created for that passTypeId, including your distribution certificate (I think) to the other developers so they could build their app with those certs in their keychain. It seems that Apple did not design passes to be sharable or consumable across developers.

**UPDATE** I have submitted a enhancement request to Apple requesting that apps can be entitled to use pass type identifiers created by other developers, requiring both certs/profiles at build time. As of today it is not possible to do so, even if all required certs/profiles are available at build time. I am not holding my breath.

Comment: You say No, however it looks like your response is affirmative. May you clarify it? What I understand of your response, that it is possible but nobody would share its passbook and distribution certificate, isn't it?

Comment: @ppcano Have you figured out the answer to your question in your comment above?